# Graphs determined by their spectrum

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Is there a place where I can find the complete list of all the graphs that are shown to be *determined by their spectrum* (*DS*) so far? Is anyone maintaining such a list? Surely, many more graphs must have been shown to be DS which aren't there in the books or survey papers. It would also be nice to have graphs which are conjectured to be DS included in that list, wouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe Huiqiu Lin, Xiaogang Liu, Jie Xue, Graphs determined by their Aα-spectra,
Discrete Mathematics, Volume 342, Issue 2, 2019, Pages 441-450, ISSN 0012-365X, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2018.10.006.
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X18303406) and its references have some useful information for you.

Comment: Had a look at that link?

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for the reference.